# Django serving static files for different folder

Tags: django

I my static folder I have admin, filebrowser, grappelli, and public.

public folder includes css, images and js, just like any folder in the static folder.

In my url.py :

```
    #Django-Grappelli
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),

    #Django-Filebrowser
    url(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include('filebrowser.urls')),

     # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    #Static
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
    }),

    #Public login
    url(r'^public/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'public/login.html'}),
```

I am able to serve the static files without any problem, but how to serve the public folder files? #Public is conflicting with #Public login.

I add this into the url.py

```
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
    }),
```

Still no luck.

```
<link href="/static/public/css/forms.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The forms.css cannot be found.

```
[05/May/2011 09:30:37] "GET /static/public/css/forms.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1751
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [many other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=serving+static+files+with+django).  You should be able to glean your answer from those.

Comment: I have tried alot of method, it is not successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the login URL pattern above the static one. Currently it will try to find a static file named `login`.